# how to permanently change the maximum recursion depth in python

Tags: python, recursion, command-line

I have a command-line python package run in the terminal directly (it was not run inside python environment) that often gives me a maximum recursion error. I know the default setting is 1000, and I know you can use the `setrecursionlimit()` command to change it. However, every time I change it and exit the python environment, the value resets to the default.

My question is, without changing the python package, is there a way I could change the python default recursion depth permanently. I understand this may not be a good practice, so I plan to change it back to 1000 after I finish using the package, which I probably won't need after a week.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps time for an iterative solution.

Comment: what does the package do?

Comment: Hard-pressed to imagine a scenario where this would be a good idea.

Comment: If you are processing a balanced tree-like structure, recursion is probably OK. If you are using out to process a list, a loop would be better. If you are using it to implement a potentially infinite loop, stop now and use a real loop. Python is not Lisp or some other functional language where recursion is the usual way to do iteration.

Comment: That said, your "python environment" is whatever runs your Python code, the interpreter that runs your script included. Just stick `sys.setrecursionlimit(...)` at the beginning of your script with a large enough value. (You could even have the limit be a command-line argument if you really need to fine tune it.) But fixing your code to not *need* a higher limit is best.

Comment: @chepner after some exploration, I realized there is no easy way to change the default setting permanently, so I went the route you suggest. More specifically, I uninstalled my original package, forked the package in github, and added the little piece of code at the top. I then reinstalled the package *FROM my github*, and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that using `sys.setrecursionlimit` is the way to go. In the end, that is the reason why `sys` is part of the Python Standard Library.

In an interactive session, you could set your `PYTHONSTARTUP` global variable to a file with the necessary python commands, however this would still run the exact same code but just a bit more 'hidden' from the user.

I think that if you'd really like to set this to another value, your only option is to dive deep into the C header files of the cpython source code and custom compile python for your needs.